# what does cv2.key( ) return?

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2
k = cv2.waitkey(0)
if k == 27:
   cv2.destroyallwindows()
```

when I use this alone

```
k = cv2.waitkey(0)
print(k)
```

it doesn't allow me to press any key and return -1
then why in the first code it will allow me to press any key?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [the documentation of `waitKey`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=waitkey#waitkey):

> **Note:** The function only works if there is at least one HighGUI window created and the window is active. If there are several HighGUI windows, any of them can be active.

If you use the function alone, there is no window open that actually waits for an input. In that case, it returns immediately with a `-1`.

Comment: thank you and one more thing why they use waitkey(0) & 0XFF? why they done use waitkey(0) alone